For loop running infinitely in go, while adding a Node to an Linked List
I am new to Golang, trying to implement some of the data structures and algo's in it,
I have written a go function that adds data to the list, but for some reason, it goes into infinite loop,I have already tried various approach to no avail, also I ended up searching for the actual code for Linked List on the internet and found various implementation, but all of them get stuck on the same place,
My Code
// linked-list.go

type Node struct {
    data int
    next *Node
}

type LinkedList struct {
    head *Node
}

func (ll *LinkedList) Add(value int) {
    node := &Node{
        data: value,
    }
    if ll.head == nil {
        ll.head = node
    }

    curr := ll.head
    for curr.next != nil {  // this is where the code gets stuck
        curr = curr.next    // this is not pointing it to the next node
    }

    curr.next = node
}

// main.go

func main() {
    ll := modules.LinkedList{}
    ll.Print()
    ll.Add(1)
    ll.Add(2)
    ll.Print()
}


Some of the codes that I tried from the internet
For ref:
golangprograms
medium blog

Have you tried debugging to stop the execution and study the execution? Depending on your IDE you can find pretty easy instructions to trigger breakpoints and walk through your algo.

Yes, I have and it basically never reassigns the curr to curr.next which results in infinite loop

Tip for the future with fmt.Printf you can print pointer addresses using %p. This has allowed me to find a few nasty problems that were hard to spot by just looking at a debugger window. In this case you could have noticed that the node and the next node would have had the same address - that of the head which may have triggered the penny to drop. Debuggers are great but sometimes just good old fashioned console logging is the best friend.

return in if condition when ll.head == nil. Currently last line of function is assigning head as head.next thus making a circular linked list which will never end.

Hey, my bad this was a rookie mistake, the return  statement fixed the whole flow.
Thanks man. :)

Yes, accepting, it is saying i need to wait 2 mins before accepting
